# Polymer 1.0 Child element not firing to parent

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm having trouble trying to fire an event from a child element to its parent on Polymer 1.0, and I can't see what am I doing wrong.

EDITED: Add more code

Child's code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../components/iron-input/iron-input.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-input/paper-input container.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-input/paper-input-error.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../components/iron-input/iron-input.html" />
<link rel="import" href="custom-table.html" />
<dom-module id="master-admin">
    <style is="custom-style">
       [...]
    </style>
    <template>
        <custom-table selectable collist="{{columns}}" data="{{data}}">
        </custom-table>
        <div id="newrow" class="horizontal layout" hidden>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{columns}}" as="col">
                <paper-input-container class="container flex">
                    <label class="label">{{col.name}}</label>
                    <input class="input" id="input" is="iron-input">
                </paper-input-container>
            </template>
        </div>
        <div id="iconsdiv" class="horizontal layout">
            <iron-icon id="adicon" icon="add-circle" on-click="addrow"></iron-icon>
            <div class="flex"></div>
            <iron-icon id="delicon" icon="cancel" on-click="delrow"></iron-icon>
            <iron-icon id="edicon" icon="create" on-click="editrow"></iron-icon>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'master-admin',
        properties: {
            doctype: String,
            columns: Array,
            data: Array
        },
        datachanged: function () {
            debugger;
            var updatedata = {
                data: this.data,
                doctype: this.doctype
            };
            this.fire('data-updated', updatedata);
        },
        addrow: function (e) {
            [...]
            this.datachanged();
        },
        delrow: function (e) {
            [...]
            this.datachanged();
        },
        editrow: function (e) {
            [...]
            this.datachanged();
        }
    });
    </script>
    </dom-module>
```

On parent:

```
<master-admin 
    doctype="{{master.DocumentalTypeId}}" 
    columns="{{master.Columns}}" 
    data="{{master.Data}}" 
    on-data-updated="masterupdated">
</master-admin>

masterupdated: function () {
    alert('updated master!');
}
```

Just to be clear, `datachanged` works just fine and it's called when it should. `masterupdated` on the parent does not.

The alert is never firing, nor the code gives any error. I guess is just something with Polymer 1.0 that works different.

Comment: Could you post your master-admin definition? Has it any dependency on core-X elements?

Comment: Seems like your `datachanged` function is not being called. How are your `observers` in `<master-admin>` set up?

Comment: dont you need a "listener" property set up in the parent element?  https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html

Comment: @zerodevx datachanged is not the problem, the code actually goes in there, it's not a property observer but a function called from other  functions after some changes, as you can see now on my question.

Comment: @RobertRowntree As far a I know this is not necessary, in fact I have something like this working just fine on another element, not listener used

Comment: Silly question - but your parent is a Polymer element as well, right? Could you post more code of your parent element - or ideally a jsbin? if you have declared the `on-*` attribute from the `<master-admin>` tag, I don't see why your `masterupdated()` function is not called.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the error on jsbin, I ended up giving up and recoding the whole thing, it works now, I guess is just a tiny mistake I was not seeing. Thanks so much for all of you trying to help, though :)

Answer (score 0):

The basic setup you describe does work, there must be a problem in the details somewhere. Here is an example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <base href="http://milestech.net/components/">

  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  
<x-parent></x-parent>
<hr>
  
<dom-module id="master-admin">
  <template>
    
    <button on-tap="updateData">Update Data</button>
    
  </template>
  <script>
    // only need this when both (1) in the main document and (2) on non-Chrome browsers
    addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      
      Polymer({
        is: 'master-admin',
        updateData: function() {
          this.fire('data-updated');
        }
        
      });
      
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
  
<dom-module id="x-parent">
  <style>

  
  </style>
  <template>
  
    <master-admin on-data-updated="masterupdated"></master-admin>

  </template>
  <script>
    // only need this when both (1) in the main document and (2) on non-Chrome browsers
    addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-parent',        
        masterupdated: function() {
          document.body.appendChild(this.create('h3', {textContent: 'data-updated!'}));
        }
        
      });
      
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

</body>
```

Comment: I actually have this setup working on another element without any problems, but can't make it on this one, I'm just lost... I've updated my question to reflect more accurately what am I doing. Thanks for your example

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```html
<template is="dom-bind" id="t">
<master-admin 
    doctype="{{master.DocumentalTypeId}}" 
    columns="{{master.Columns}}" 
    data="{{master.Data}}" 
    on-data-updated="masterupdated">
</master-admin>
  </template>

<script>
 var template = document.querySelector('#t');
 template.masterupdated= function () {
 consloe.log("MASTER UPDATED!!");
     };
</script>
```